# How do I link a DynamoDB, Lambda Function, or Gateway API to an external API with a POST function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless

I want to preface this with the fact that I'm not knowledgable with AWS really at all. I mostly do front end development and some very (very, very) basic MySQL.

Recently a new manager has joined my company and despite telling him, he seems to think I'm a backend developer. Because of that I've been tasked with hooking up an AWS flow that was in place (A DynamoDB table, an Gateway API and Lambda Function that connects them and also creates gists with tokens) to an external API that accepts data with a POST function.

Ideally I'd like to not have to touch anything to do with the Lambda function as I'm not 100% of how it works and the files are too big to do inline editing within the AWS dashboard.

Is there anyway I can set this up easily? Any help would be incredibly appreciated

p.s. Don't feel bad about talking down to me or anything. The easier and more clearly explained the better

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not something I can just spit out here. You will have to do some learning and homework. That said here are some resources where you can learn quickly what you are trying to find out.

1. [AWS Serverless home page](http://aws.amazon.com/serverless)
2. [Serverless.com lambda information](https://www.serverless.com/aws-lambda/)
3. [AWS Serverless blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/tag/serverless/)
4. [AWS Serverless tutorials](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/resources/?serverless.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&serverless.sort-order=desc)
5. [AWS Serverless hands on building apps](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/)
6. [AWS Serverless youtube channel](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/)
7. [AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/)
8. [Free Amazon DynamoDB online training from Linux Academy](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/resources/training-linux-academy/)